# Better way to write statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL Server 2016:

```
select TitleNumber, PCount, * 
from Staging
where id = 2163 and PCount >= 3500
or id = 2163 and titleNumber != 0
Order by title
```

I need to pull out the records from Staging table that meet one of these conditions:
1.  narrow selection to loaded file (id column) and only give records that count >= 3500
2.  narrow selection to loaded file (id column) and only give records where titlenumber does not = 0

Is there a better way to write this than having to state the id condition twice?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `Count` is a very bad name for a column.  `COUNT` is a keyword, and case is not significant in SQL. [maybe you intended to `select count(*)` ? ]

Comment: See [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
select s.* 
from Staging s
where id = 2163 and (Count >= 3500 or titleNumber <> 0)
Order by title
```

Note that I removed the explicit mention of `titleNumber` and `count` from the `select`.  These are already included in the `*`, so it is unclear why they need to be selected twice.  (If you have a reason, you can include them, of course.)

Comment: If we are showing the best and fastest way to write the query, shouldn't we point out that not using the wildcard in the select is better in terms of performance and maintainability?

Comment: that's a good point Hogan.  Thank you.  I will add specific columns.